# Arredondamento para cima de float em javascript

Tags: javascript

Qual seria a maneira mais elegante de arredondar um float em 2 casas decimais sempre para cima em javascript?

Ex: 2,453 = 2,46

Answer (score -1):

Tenta isto:

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary

Ou no teu caso, faz algo do tipo:

```
var arrendondar = Math.round(num * 100);
var resultado = Math.ceil(arredondar)/100;
```