# Arredondamento de casas decimais

Tags: javascript

Possuo o seguinte valor: `6.175`

Quando eu utilizo o `.toFixed(2)` nesse número o valor correto que deveria ser retornado é `6.18`, certo?

[Arredondamento](https://www.portaleducacao.com.br/conteudo/artigos/educacao/regras-de-arredondamento/30568)

Porém estou obtendo `6.17` como retorno. Há outra forma de realizar esse arredondamento para que seja feito de forma correta?

Comment: Veja isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207612/5878

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas pelo que é dito uma das respostas o `.toFixed()` deveria arredondar para cima, e nesse caso está fazendo o oposto disso

Comment: (Math.round(6.175 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) não resolveu pra você? (nota: não testei com outros valores para ver como essa função se comporta)

Comment: Também notei que 6.175 tem problemas com a representação IEEE 754, ele seria assim na verdade: 6.17499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875, acho que por isso o toFixed(2) retorna 6.17